# How to handle "Steam" friend at job?

Tags: colleagues

When I started this new job 3 months ago, a coworker saw me checking Steam App and he asked me which games I am playing and we talked about it. Then he suggested that we add each other as friends as Steam so that we could play some multiplayer games together. For 1 month it was going well. When I go home I was spending some time with this guy at evenings but as time passes, this guy started asking me questions like why weren't you online yesterday? What were you doing? At first I was giving some excuses but the problem is he spends so much time at evenings at Steam and I do not normally play that much maybe I spend quarter of time he spends I spend every day. (1 hour max) I feel that he is stalking me too by looking at the history of my games. (Especially Dota 2) And then the next day he is asking me hey I saw you made 2 matches yesterday and did not play the day before yesterday...I think that he feels that he is betrayed or some other feeling I have no idea... I also think he has some issues... I don't want to expose my playing hours or the games I play to him so I thought about removing him from friends but by doing this  because I work with him at job everytime, I will give him a reason to complain so I did not do this yet.

What I am asking is, have you ever faced a situation and a person like this in your workplace and how did you handle this? How should I get rid of him stalking me in Steam and at the same time not destroying my relation with my colleague?

Note: Removing him from my friends will destroy our friendship at job and will deteriorate my career. Also I am new in this job and he is far way more experienced than me. So this is not an option.

Comment: This may be a better fit for IPS, since it seems more about interpersonal skills than the workplace in general.

Comment: That would be  https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit for [Interpersonal Skills](http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Snow Just because its better fit in another site doesn't mean is offtopic here. He ask about how handling a coworker and avoid any problem at work

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  There's nothing here that is specifically workplace related.

Comment: @Snow I guess we will disagree on that, because isn't the same a coworker stalking you on steam than a neighbour. Like isn't the same a noisy coworker than a noisy neighbour

Comment: Just say that you feel more like playing solo campaign sometimes. Play one or two with him from time to time and things will slowly fade away.

Comment: this is THE reason I don't add coworkers on anything like game sites or Facebook or anything. I just say that to people that ask me to become friends on whatever network/app; "Sorry but I like to keep what I do in my private time separated from work time." I guess it is a little too late for that now, but keep it in mind for the future. For now I  would tell him you just don't want to play games every night and you don't owe him an explanation for why you played other people and not him :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This guy started asking me questions like why weren't you online yesterday? What were you doing?

There's two general ways of handling this that I'd go with - the jovial way:

> Ah, well if I told you that I'd have to kill you ;)

...which may or may not get a laugh, depending on the type of person. Alternatively, the down to earth way:

> I don't like playing games every evening, I find it sometimes gets a bit tiring so I'll often watch TV or (insert other activity here that you do on your own and can't be shared) instead.

In this particular case, you may also wish to use one of a few unofficial methods to [hide your steam history](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=633673692), so he can't start any conversations along those lines. But assuming you don't, and he sees that you've played games without him:

> I wasn't feeling so social last night - sometimes I just fancy a few games on my own.

Don't overthink it, don't be drawn into a long conversation about "why", and don't be apologetic. Just clearly state a short reason, and that should be more than enough for him to move on and stop bugging you.

Answer (score 3):

Being honest helps in these situations. Just state that you do not play the game as much, and you only played it because you were interested spending time with your coworker after hours.

It'll eventually fade away. He's probably interested in you only because you're the only other co-worker who plays the game.

You say you're concerned because he keeps looking at your profile. Yet you looked at his profile and know that he plays many more hours than you. So you're both guilty of this and you can't hold him on that. It may just be that he doesn't have any other way to spend his time.

Comment: *"Games are for fun, bro.  Don't make it weird."*  100% agree with this answer.